# Access Violation 'deleting' pointers at the destructor

Tags: c++, exception, memory, c++11, access-violation

My Binary Search Tree destructor looks like this.

```
~BSTree()
{
    if (this == nullptr || this->left == nullptr && this->right == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }
    this->left->~BSTree();
    delete this->left;
    this->right->~BSTree();
    delete this->right;
}
```

After the call stack gets about >= 4 calls my program crashes at the `if()` with the **Access Voilation Exception**.

My fields are only three: `int key;`,`BSTree *left;` and `BSTree *right;`

[image]

it seems that `this` is not NULL but its fields cannot be read from the memory. **How do I check if they can and `remove this;` if not to prevent the exception?**

Comment: Don't call the destructors by yourself. `delete` will do this for you.

Comment: You involve the destructor twice for each node

Comment: `this == nullptr` isn't very useful.

Comment: Chnossos, Dieter Lücking you're right, I didn't know that `delete` calls the destructor; I thought it was only to clear the memory. Mat, what should I use?

Comment: "what should I use" - to do what?  By definition, `this` cannot be null.  (This test can only succeed if your program has entered undefined-behaviour land from an earlier mistake, in which case all bets are off anyway)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple things :

1. Don't call a destructor by yourself unless used with a placement new.
2. By the C++ Standard, `this` can't be equal to `nullptr`. If it is, you have more serious problems.
3. `delete` already calls the destructor automatically.
4. `delete` can be passed a `nullptr` without problem.

Your destructor should look like :

```
~BSTree()
{
    delete left;
    delete right;
    // possibly ...
    left = right = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: You should also set `this->right = nullptr;` after deleteing.

Comment: @Chnossos, can you plz explain why "this cannot be equal to nullptr"?

Comment: The C++ Standard says that it does not make sense, although in rare case it _could_ happen, but it is always an error. [Check this](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1844005%2Fchecking-if-this-is-null&ei=JtlkU_WiDMGGOPOKgbgK&usg=AFQjCNG6cUo8qtAgF7GTVWLs-_nLH29okw&sig2=WdISV5TRX4hybij96-3PPQ).

Comment: "this" can be NULL / nullptr. Whether the standard says so or not is irrelevant. It can happen. Simply call a method on a NULL pointer. So long as the method doesn't read/write any data members or call any virtual functions you won't get a crash (crazy stuff!). MFC is even written to handle that case (some, not all classes).

Answer (score 4):

Below code should be adequate, delete null pointer is valid.

```
~BSTree()
{
  delete left;
  delete right;
}
```

Comment: You should also set `this->right = nullptr;` after deleteing.

Comment: it's almost unnecessary as the object itself is being deleted, no any further reference would likely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like this

```
   ~BSTree()
   {
     if ( this->left != nullptr){
          delete this->left;
          this->left= nullptr;
     }
     if(this->right != nullptr){
       delete this->right;
       this->right = nullptr;
     }
  }
```

delete operator does 2 things sequentially:

1. Calls destructor
2. De-allocates memory

you should not call destructor manually. And one common sense, the dest method is called on `this` object, so how `this` can be `null` (it is possible to call destructor on null object, but then it is a bug and the check `this==nullptr` will not help there).

Comment: You should also set `this->right = nullptr;` after deleteing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, does not the delete operator do this?

Comment: @RakibulHasan No it doesn't.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and Chnossos, thank you guys. I also learned something.

Comment: `this->right` no longer exists as soon as the object is destroyed, so the compiler could optimise out the line `this->right = nullptr;` anyway. I don't see why it "should also" be done